# How to run script when cell is change

Tags: google-sheets

I have this script in Google Sheets, i want it to run when cell A6 changes to "Accept" I need to do this because Google Sheets dont show drawings when using tablet.

I found out its starts with `function onOpen(e)`

Someone knows how to do this?

My code :

```
function Melding() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = sheet.getRange(7, 7).getValue();
  var message = '';
  }
  var subject = 'Update : '+sheet.getRange(4, 2).getValue();
  var body = 'text ' + sheet.getRange(4, 2).getValue() + ' text. ' + '\n' + '\nFølg link for å se endringer : ' + ss.getUrl() + '\n' + '\n' + 'text : ' + '\n' + '" ' + sheet.getRange(6, 7).getValue() + ' " ' + '\n ' + '\n (Google) ' + '\n' + '\n - VS ' + message +'';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('G6').setValue('No MSG');
  Browser.msgBox('Takk for det' , 'MSG sent to : '+sheet.getRange(7, 7).getValue()+ '\n' + '  - (From : '+email+')', Browser.Buttons.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

an onOpen trigger makes the script run when the spreadsheet is opened. What you need is onEdit(). See here for [more documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). You can test by wrapping your function in an onEdit.

```
function onEdit(e) {
if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'A6' || e.value !== 'Accept') return;
Melding()
}
```

Then set A6 to Accept and see if that fires your function 'Melding'. Note that if you want to 'limit' the script to just one sheet in the spreadsheet you will have to add a extra condition.

If it works as intended, you can optimize the script..

Comment: Hi, thanks. 

It look like the code dont work? Do i have to add a trigger?


`function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'A6' || e.value !== 'Accept') return;
Melding()
}`

Comment: I see you try to log the current user. If you want to do that for 'other' user they will have to authorize the script first. Can you maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet, so I can try to optimize the code a little ?

Comment: Hi, i dont need to log the current user. The sheet is in norwegian. Is it possible to send email from my mail from the script even if your are anonymus user? Follow this link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U0RgwZCm-H4o-tkvERicaYBMuZ8dxty7OhlYlRpHzdM/edit?usp=sharing